# Populate datatable using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am trying to populate a data table using ajax call. But it fill only the first column with last value from `columns`.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.2.32:5000/get_all_locations",
    'method': 'GET',
    'contentType': 'application/json'
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log('dataaa', data);
    $('#myTable').dataTable({
      'aaData': data['data'],
      "columns": [{
        "data": "id",
        "data": "name",
        "data": "code"
      }]
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

[image]

In the above image, id field show value of code.
How can i resolve this?

Output of data

```
    {…}
    ​
    StatusCode: true
    ​
    StatusDescription: "Location details has been pulled successfully."
    ​
    data: (9) […]
    ​​
    0: Object { code: "1007", id: 20, is_free_zone: true, … }
    ​​
    1: Object { code: "1002", id: 15, is_free_zone: false, … }
    ​​
    2: Object { code: "1001", id: 14, is_free_zone: false, … }
    ​​
    3: Object { code: "1003", id: 16, is_free_zone: false, … }
    ​​
    4: Object { code: "1004", id: 17, is_free_zone: false, … }
    ​​
    5: Object { code: "1006", id: 19, is_free_zone: false, … }
    ​​
    6: Object { code: "1005", id: 18, is_free_zone: false, … }
    ​​
    7: Object { code: "1008", id: 21, is_free_zone: false, … }
    ​​
    8: Object { code: "1009", id: 22, is_free_zone: false, … }
    ​​
    length: 9
```

Comment: What do you get from doing `console.log('dataaa', data.data)`?

Comment: Your column config looks wrong, you have an object with three properties with the same name, so you're only creating one column? Shouldn't it be a map from property name to column header?

Comment: @palaѕн, output posted in updated question.

Comment: @JuanMendes, could you please give an example? because i am a beginner in this.
which property should i given there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Each column should be a separate object with a data property pointing to the name of the property on the record.

```
columns: [
    {"data": "id"},
    {"data": "name"},
    {"data": "code"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column def is an object instead of an array of objects.

Each column config *needs* a `data` field and an optional `title`.

```js
let data = requestData();

$(() => {
  $("#myTable").DataTable({
    aaData: data['data'],
    columns: [
      { "data" : "id"   , "title": "ID"   },
      { "data" : "name" , "title": "Name" },
      { "data" : "code" , "title": "Code" }
    ]
  })
});

function requestData() {
  return {
    data : [
      { code: "1007", id: 20, name: "a", is_free_zone: true  },
      { code: "1002", id: 15, name: "b", is_free_zone: false },
      { code: "1001", id: 14, name: "c", is_free_zone: false },
      { code: "1003", id: 16, name: "d", is_free_zone: false },
      { code: "1004", id: 17, name: "e", is_free_zone: false },
      { code: "1006", id: 19, name: "f", is_free_zone: false },
      { code: "1005", id: 18, name: "g", is_free_zone: false },
      { code: "1008", id: 21, name: "h", is_free_zone: false },
      { code: "1009", id: 22, name: "i", is_free_zone: false }
    ]
  };
}
```

```css
#myTable th, #myTable td { padding: 0.33em }
#myTable th { font-size: 0.90em }
#myTable td { font-size: 0.75em }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-wrapper">
  <!-- https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4 -->
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Code</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follow

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.2.32:5000/get_all_locations",
        'method': 'GET',
        'contentType': 'application/json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log('dataaa', data);
        $('#myTable').dataTable({
            'aaData': data['data'],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", },
                { "data": "name", },
                {"data": "code",},
            }]
        })
    })
```

you can customise each column by adding filtring or enabling search :

```
{"data": "code","orderable": false, "searchable": false,},
```

Comment: Answers should not just post working code, they should explain what the problem was